# synchronizing two 8250 uarts on separate clocks (microcontrollers)

Tags: synchronization, microcontroller, uart, 8051

I'm trying to figure out the best algorithm to use to get my client microcontroller (8051) to automatically synchronize its uart with the master microcontroller (also 8051) so that communication can happen. The bottleneck is that the uarts can only hold one byte. The microcontrollers are actually AT89S52's so each instruction executes in 1/2 to 1 microsecond since I'm using 22.1184Mhz crystals with 33pF NPO capacitors.

This is the code I have so far. P3.0 is the receive pin on the microcontroller (where the bits of data come in).

The last four lines of code setup the serial port so I can use the software interrupts.

The value for SPEED is a calculated number on the 8051 that determines baud. I use the value of 0FDh because the UART speed is 38.4Kbps. The keil's baud rate calculator is what I use to best determine SPEED value.

```
redosync:
    jb P3.0,$ ;scan line twice to see if line is low (is this enough times?)
    jb P3.0,$
    ;Wait for the time of 8 bytes 
    mov TH1,#((256 - SPEED) * 8) 
    w:
      mov ACC,#06h
      djnz ACC,$
    djnz TL1,w 
  ;check end byte twice to see if its a 1
  ;if in any check its not a 1, then start the sync all over again
  jnb P3.0,redosync
  jnb P3.0,redosync
  ;Here the UART is in sync so set it up
  mov TL1,#SPEED
  mov PCON,#80h
  mov SCON,#50h
  setb TR1
```

Am I on the right track with my synchronization idea?
If so, then am I scanning the bits enough times?
And would things improve if I changed the data?

Currently the data format is as follows:

ffh, ffh for start bytes
15 bytes of raw data
then 1 byte representing checksum of the 15 bytes

Comment: Which problem do you try to solve with this synchronization? Do you know that the UART module synchronizes itself on falling edge of the start bit? This is the idea behind **asynchronous** serial communication. The idle level on an asynchronous serial line is 1, the start bit is 0, followed by data bits, and (if used) one parity bit and the stop bit. The stop bit is 1 so another byte can follow immediately.

Comment: this is exactly what uarts are good at, differently clocked systems communicating with each other.  what happens when you set up the uarts normally and use them normally, even a single character should go through just fine.

Comment: are you using hardware uarts or trying to reverse big bang one in software?